# Problem converting shapes to outlines in Sketch App

Tags: svg, sketch-app

I'm trying to upload some custom icons to FontAwesome and when uploading the svg file I get the error:

> This SVG contains strokes that need be expanded.
> There were strokes detected in your SVG. You'll need to convert all shapes to outlines in your source file, re-export the SVG, and try uploading again.

I'm exporting the svg via Sketch App but I'm not able to find a 'convert shapes to outlines' function and, to be honest, I'm not really sure that I understand what they are asking me to do.

The svg contains a few shapes all combined with intersect operation.

I've tried combining them in different ways and or use masking without success. I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I'm not a Sketch user, but [in the user manual](https://www.sketch.com/docs/designing/vector-editing/) - scroll down to where it says "**Turning a border into outlines**. Select any shape with a border and select Layer > Convert to Outlines"